# New version of Android Studio is not opening

Tags: android-studio

I  recently downloaded a new version of Android Studio, but after installation of the program, it asked options like to create new projects or others as I click on the project structure where I had to locate the path of the SDK. After locating its path correctly, it just froze. Nothing happens when I click the create a new project option. Instead of this, I clicked open the current project option. Android Studio opened, but without the SDK settings. When I go to the SDK manager to locate the path of SDK, that SDK manager option is not loading. It keeps on loading and shows nothing.

This problem is only related to the new version, not with the Android Studio 1.5. What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Why the tag spamming

Comment: `javascript` `c#` `php` `c` lmao

Comment: Most probably your system is performing a bit slower for the new Android Studio Version.Wait for it to launch properly & try downloading required things from SDK manager once it opens. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

**i hope this command help you!!**
For linux

open Terminal

Follow this commmand

```
 cd /media/ubuntu/DATA/android-studio/bin

./studio.sh
```

For Windows

Follow this commmand

```
cd /media/ubuntu/DATA/android-studio/bin

./studio.sh
```